# Call a function on screen size change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using JQuery to manage the style of a menu on my website. What I'm trying to get is to have two separate functions executed, the first should be executed when the width of the window is greater than 800 pixels, the second when it is smaller than 800 pixels. In the example below, Switch_Menu() gets called when the page is loading and eventually if the windows gets resized. Same goes for portrait/landscape mode on a tablet. Everything seems to be working fine, but I have no idea how to manage the switch between the two states: I'm trying to find a way to stop the first function and run the second when the width is changed.

What I've done so far is essentially the following concept:

```
function Switch_Menu() {
if ($(window).width() > 800) { 
//function 1 is called
//where some objects on the page get hidden, some get resized
}
else { 
//function 2 is called
////where some objects on the page get hidden, some get resized
}
}

Switch_Menu();
$(window).resize(function() {Switch_Menu();});
```

If I use this piece of code, I have no problem when the page gets load for the first time, and only the correct function gets executed. However, when the screen size is changed, both the functions get executed at the same time, like there was no 'if' block.

Do you have any idea how I could do this? Should I use another kind of JavaScript specific feature for such a task?

Comment: *`$(window).on('load resize', function(){ Switch_Menu(); });`*, this will run on  both, window *`load`* as well as on window *`resize`*